# PHP Parse images from Google Images

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

The question is quite simple. I'm able to parse image from Google Images website by using the following code:

```
$search_keyword=str_replace(' ','+',$search_keyword);
$newhtml =file_get_html("https://www.google.com/search?q=".$search_keyword."&tbm=isch");
$result_image_source = $newhtml->find('img');
foreach($result_image_source as $div) {
    echo '<img src="'.$div->src.'">';
}
```

but I only get encrypted images, that is I got the right images but in a very small size. How can I scrape the real size images, instead? The code works in PHP with Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Google Image Search API to get image results in a nice JSON object instead of scraping them?

https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide?hl=en#json_snippets_php

Comment: I thought it did not work anymore (marked as deprecated)

Comment: Indeed, if I run it, I got `{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "This API is no longer available.", "responseStatus": 403}`

Comment: I spoke to quickly, then. When I last used the deprecated API it still allowed 1000 requests a day. I guess that has changed.

Comment: Yes, I used it too, but since few months it has been blocked. :(